# get a component of a function that returns an svg component react

Tags: reactjs, svg

I would like to convert the code of an svg into a react component knowing that the svg comes from a db table.
So I have a function that returns me a react component of my svg but I cannot use it in the rest of my code

```
import svgr from '@svgr/core'
const ColorPicker =  (props) => {
  svgr(props.svg, { icon: true }, { componentName: 'MyComponent' }).then(
    (jsCode) => {
      console.log(jsCode)
    },
  )
  return (
      <div className="colorpickerdisplay">
        <button className="Color1"/>
      </div>
  )
}
export default ColorPicker;
```

jscode's console.log displays the react component well, but I cannot display it in the div, for example. could you help me? have a good day